# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/generic-sts/sts.jsp'

Tags: wso2-api-manager

### Enviroments:

- WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1
- OS: Ubuntu 12.08
- JDK: 1.7

### Problem:

When I tried to add a service provider on the carbon web console and enabled SAML2 Web SSO Configuration and clicked Configurate I had an error with next message:

```
[2015-10-27 17:32:42,713] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sso-saml/add_service_provider.jsp
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:463)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:700)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at  org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_ins`enter code here`ertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
```

Comment: when i built a carbon project version 4.4.2 worked without exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start APIM in Linux Environment please verify wso2server.sh file has following configuration.

```
-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false \”
```

If you starts the APIM as a window service, in carbon 4.4.x, default wrapper.conf file needs to be updated with following additional entries.

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dwso2.carbon.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\carbon.xml
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dwso2.registry.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\registry.xml
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dwso2.user.mgt.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\user-mgt.xml
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dwso2.transports.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\mgt-transports.xml
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

You can verify these configurations in wrapper.conf and these configurations may help you to solve the jsp error.